# intel GMA 3600 can't be detected

Tags: drivers, intel

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but my graphics adapter (Intel GMA 3600) can't be detected. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the GMA 3600 drivers are only 32-bit and only compatible with older kernels.

Given that Intel abandoned support for the GMA 3600 hardware, even for Microsoft Windows, using the generic VESA driver with a recent Ubuntu release is probably a better choice.

Comment: o, so sad. :( where can i find VESA driver? can u give me the link?

Comment: Install the `xserver-xorg-video-vesa` package.  It is a standard X11 package.